# Python Itertools combination

Tags: python, combinations

I would like to find combination of an array contents with the index. Also, with dynamic combination length. Right now I can combine with this without returning index:

```
print("Combination result: ")
for L in range(1, len(splitword)+1):
    comb = combinations(splitword, L)
    for combine in comb:
        print(combine)
```

How can I return index too along with the combination ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `combinations(range(len(splitword)), L)` instead to find the indices. Then finding the values from there is simple indexing.

```
print("Combination result: ")
for L in range(1, len(splitword)+1):
    comb = itertools.combinations(range(len(splitword)), L)
    for combination_index in comb:
        print(combination_index, [splitword[i] for i in combination_index])
```

Comment: wow, awesome ! thanks, I am learning your code right now, I am beginner with itertools, can you explain me a bit about things above ?

Comment: What I did is not related to ``itertools``. Rather than generating combinations of the letters in your string, I just shuffled a ``range``, i.e. the numbers from 0 to ``len(splitword)``. Notice that this amounts to rearranging the indices, and not the values themselves.